# Using ifaddrs library in Swift

Tags: ios, xcode, swift

I´m not able to import ifaddrs to my Swift project. The compiler says:

**No such module "ifaddrs"**

Aim is to get iPhones IP address in the current wifi network at the end. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Normally under your file ****-Bridging-Header.h (where **** is the name of your project - xcode creates it for you when you include objective c resources) you have to add:

> `#include <arpa/inet.h>`
>
> `#include <sys/socket.h>`
>
> `#include <ifaddrs.h>`

After ifaddrs is added to the bridge file, the objective c class can be used in swift.